# Win32 Device Events : Not receiving DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME on DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL event

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

What I'm basically trying to do is making a windows service that listens to storage device insertion such as (USB flash drive, external HDD/SSD)...
I'm follwing these 2 tutorials :

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15612/Receiving-Device-Event-Notification-in-Windows-Ser
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/detecting-media-insertion-or-removal

I got the service part running correctly, I'm also receiving Device Notifications.
 **But** when I try to put a USB flash drive, I receive a notification but `dbch_devicetype` in `PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR`is always `DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE` never `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME`. Also when I `RegisterDeviceNotification` with `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME` I don't receive anything. I have been searching for hours and I could't find why I'm not receiving the correct notifications
The function responsible for registering the Service for device notifications :

```
void Myclassname::registerForDeviceNotifications() {
    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;
    ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter));
    NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
    NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = { 0x71a27cdd, 0x812a, 0x11d0, 0xbe, 0xc7, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe2, 0x09, 0x2f };

    m_hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(m_statusHandle,
        &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE |
        DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES);
}
```

The function responsible for handling the device notifications :

```
void AutobackupService::handleDeviceChangeNotif(DWORD dwEventType, LPVOID lpEventData) {
    switch (dwEventType) {
    case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE: {
        PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR eventData = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lpEventData;
        logToFile(std::to_string(eventData->dbch_devicetype));
        if (eventData->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
        {
            PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME lpdbv = (PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)eventData;
            if (lpdbv->dbcv_flags & DBTF_MEDIA)
            {
                WriteEventLogEntry(L"USB device removed " + lpdbv->dbcv_unitmask, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
            }
        }
    }
                                   break;
    case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL: {
        PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR eventData = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lpEventData;
        logToFile(std::to_string(eventData->dbch_devicetype));
        if (eventData->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
        {
            PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME lpdbv = (PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)eventData;
            if (lpdbv->dbcv_flags & DBTF_MEDIA)
            {
                WriteEventLogEntry(L"USB device removed " + lpdbv->dbcv_unitmask, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: you and must got `dbcc_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE` because you register for `NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;` and you need use `NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME`   instead `GUID_DEVCLASS_VOLUME`

Comment: @RbMm I tried using <code>GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME</code> and it didn't work (I received notifications for the flash drive but it also registred the mouse as a storage device)

Comment: because too many errors in your code

Comment: @RbMm no the code compiles alright

Comment: how here how code compiles is related ?

Comment: @RbMm you said I have many errors in my code, i told you I changed the code like you told me, it compiled successfully, but it didn't work as expected (i.e it registered the mouse as a storage device)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200790/discussion-between-mekacher-anis-and-rbmm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at first your wrong register for volume notification. code must be

```
        static DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter = { 
            sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE), 
            DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE,
            0,
            GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME
        };

        m_hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(m_statusHandle,
             &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE);
```

note than need use `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME` if you want volume arrival/removal notification but not `GUID_DEVCLASS_VOLUME` (you use it as `{ 0x71a27cdd, 0x812a, 0x11d0, 0xbe, 0xc7, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe2, 0x09, 0x2f };`). with `GUID_DEVCLASS_VOLUME` you never got notifications, because this is not interface guid. you got notifications only because use set `DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES` flag - Notifies the recipient of device interface events for all device interface classes. (The dbcc_classguid member is **ignored**.)

then in handler - you must got `dbcc_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE` type of notification (not `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME`) also will be `dbcc_classguid == GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME` if you register exactly for `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME` only. so you can cast `lpEventData` to `PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` and use `dbcc_name` member - this is win32 symbolic link to volume name (can be used in call `CreateFileW`)

Comment: can you give me an example of using `dbcc_name` to open the drive ?

Comment: @MekacherAnis - how i say - simply pass it to call `CreateFileW` as first parameter